# Could I authenticate to a known WiFi using PMK only?

Tags: wifi, wpa

I have stored the PMK from a WiFi on my computer. Now I forgot the password to the WiFi. Is it possible, to connect back to the WiFi only with the PMK?

Answer (score 1):

The PMK is nothing else but the passphrase and the SSID of the network run through some rounds of hashing.

So the PMK "format" is required by any client device that wants to  connect to the network anyhow. However, the big question is whether the Wi-Fi manager on your computer allows you to enter a PMK instead of a passphrase? Windows 10 "native" Wi-Fi manager does not, neither does Ubuntu.

For Windows systems, however, you may use the command line tool netsh to create a network profile with the PMK included. Dump all Wi-Fi profiles on the system first:

```
netsh wlan export profile
```

Pick one of the .xml files that are being created by this command and adapt it to your needs. In order to enter the PMK to the profile (instead of key material), set "protected" to "false" and simple enter you passphrase as keyMaterial, e.g.:

```
  <sharedKey>
    <keyType>networkKey</keyType>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <keyMaterial>Your_64_hex_PMK_here</keyMaterial>
  </sharedKey>
```

Of course, you need also to change the SSID of the network, etc...

Import the profile back into the system using this command:

```
netsh wlan add profile myprofile.xml
```

Find more information on the Microsoft Website: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/intune/configuration/wi-fi-profile-shared-key 
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/wlan-profileschema-keymaterial-sharedkey-element

So all above is a little ... uhmm ... complicated. If the essence of your question was: "How can I recover the passphrase from a saved Wi-Fi profile in Windows?", the solution would simply be:

```
netsh wlan show profile ProfileName key=clear
```

You can then read the passphrase from the response in clear text and use it for any new connection.

Comment: I think that’s what I’m looking for, a manager which allows me to enter the PMK

Comment: I have edited my original answer. It is an adaptation of the solution outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063045/connect-to-new-wifi-network-with-cmd/60078750#60078750

Comment: Added solution via "netsh wlan show profile ProfileName key=clear" to the initial solution.